# Thread in zip files download

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

What i am trying to do is create a zip file and download those files.
Here is my controller

```
     public FilePathResult Download(string Name)
         {
        string f1=null;
        try
        {
             f1 = _dbBackupServiceService.DownloadBackupFile(Name);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

            return File(f1, "application/zip", Name + ".zip");
  }
```

Also the service layer looks like this

```
    public string  DownloadBackupFile(string Name)
    {

        string backupFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DbBackup");
        string filePath = backupFolder + "\\" + Name;
        string zipFilePath = filePath.Substring(0, (filePath.Length - 3)) + "zip";

        var backupFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        var zipFileName = Path.GetFileName(zipFilePath);

          if (File.Exists(zipFilePath))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(zipFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, Name);



        }
        return zipFilePath;



    }
```

The problem i am facing is while i click on download action for those files whose zip file is not created. The processor will be creating the zip file continuously when the download threads runs and hencee and the browser displays error. while the zip files which are already created gets downloaded successfully. How can i wait until the zip file is created successfully before the download takes place?

Comment: usually that takes a lot of time, let your user go, and later inform him with an e-mail that the zip is finish and here is the link for download...

Answer (score -1):

Please add the below statement

Thread.Sleep(5000); //This will make the thread to sleep for 5 seconds.

after the statement

zip.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, Name);

If you still get the issue, increase the sleep time.

Comment: what a bad idea ! avoid it